# Make PNG Image with PHP

Tags: php, image-processing, png

I am searching if we can make PNG Image with php.

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
$black = imagecolorallocate($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$black);
```

This would create 100 X 100 black image. 
But, I want to create 100 X 100 image with no background, i.e 100 X 100 transparent Image.

Thanks in advance

Comment: check out the documentation about imagecolorallocatealpha http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php

Comment: And of course you need to output it with `imagepng($image)` http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can choose one color to become the transparent one like so:

```
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);

$transparent = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($im, $transparent);

imagefill($im, 0, 0, $transparent);
```

As taken from the manual example: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
imagesavealpha($image, true);
$transparent = 0xFF000000; //0xAARRGGBB
imagefill($image, 0, 0, $transparent);
```

Answer (score 0):

heres the function  you need:

```
imagecolorallocatealpha ( resource $image , int $red , int $green , int $blue , int $alpha )
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(100,100);
$transparent = imagecolorallocatealpha ($image,0,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$transparent);
```